# Datatable.net data indexOf vs data missmatch

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to find the index of a row that match with a column data value. From the found index I would like to get the corresponding TR element. Here is how I'm doing it :

```js
// A table with many people [name, position, office, age, etc...]
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Finding the row index of the person having 46 year old
var pos = table.column(3).data().indexOf("46");

// Getting position 7 (Cara Stevens)
console.log(`pos : ${pos}`);

// Getting data of the row at index 7
var dt = table.row(pos).data();

// We are getting Rhona Davidson instead of Cara Stevens, what's that ?
// Even if I try to get the TR html element by calling table.row(pos).node(), 
// obviously this will not be the TR having (Cara Stevens) but the one 
// with (Rhona Davidson)
console.log(`dt : ${dt}`);
```

Did I miss something about the Datatable.net and the internal index behavior or there a bg ?

Here is the complete working example of the problem, read the console result :
https://jsfiddle.net/fzvsvfs2/

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For get the correct row you should use:

```
var dt = table.rows().data()[pos];
```

because the `row(pos)`, is selecting the row of index pos from the original rows model, but not the display order, you can hava a look using `console.log(table.data())`.

For get the tr, just:

```
table.rows().nodes()[pos]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. And what about getting the TR element ? 'table.rows().node[pos]' ? I found this plugin sometime counter intuitive :(

Comment: @erakis `table.rows().nodes()[pos] `will be Ok

Comment: Thank you so much Jiangang :) I finally found explanation on datatable.net documentation. `both are in data index order, while rows().data() will return the full data set, but in the current display order (as defined by order())` on https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()